# Loading value from Firestore to android studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to using firestore and android studio  and am trying to load data from Firestore to an android studio application based on the current logged in user. This is the code I've been testing but it doesn't seem to be displaying any data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public void userInfo(){
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("users").document(userId);
    documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if(snapshot!=null){
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    String name1 = String.valueOf(snapshot.get("name:"));
                    name.setText(name1);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `if(task.isSuccessful()){` so what if the task isn't successful ? or `if(snapshot.exists())` is false ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information a_local_nobody asked for, and please also respond with @.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you wanna display the data but I don't see any code for displaying the data. If this is the case you can simply use Toast function to do this after the

```
name.setText(name1);
Toast.makeText(activityOfYours.this, name1 ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If `name` is a TextView then did you ever called the `userInfo()` method in your activity class please share more code (all activity and XML) so I can understand the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33247402)